# Updated to VBox 5.0.20, now cant install guest additions

Tags: apt, upgrade, virtualbox

I cloned a fresh copy of kali2, did apt-get update.  apt-get dist-upgrade(installed fine).  Tried with and without installing dkms. (dkms is installed on host(ubuntu) before virtualbox upgrade). Then I try theese two commands which fail because of missing headers.

http://pastebin.com/WgHNGyNH

I was able to install guest additions fine before upgrade to new version of vbox.

Comment: Kali Linux is not an official flavour of or even based on Ubuntu and therefore off topic here. Instead you may ask about it on [Unix.SE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this commands

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
```

Mount VBoxGuesAdditions CD and an icon is going to show up on your desktop, right click on it and click on 'Open in terminal'...then run this command

```
sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

and reboot

Comment: I get same error, cannot find linux headers.  I will try to reinstall kali2 virtual machine and if that doesnt work   I will reinstall VBox.  The kali2 virtual machine was a fresh copy never altered.  It would be nice to know how to fix this, rather than resorting to reinstallation.

Comment: can you post that error

Comment: I have updated my answer with these 3 commands try it

Comment: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-686-pae E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-686-pae' E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-686-pae' – –

Comment: Have you tried those 3 commands in my answer?

Comment: Yes I did.  They executed without a problem, what should i do next?

Comment: yes all 3 commands in that particular order and then go to my video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8e9PJXqBdc on 8:00 and follow the procedure to install VBoxLinuxAdditions

Comment: Then something was wrong just with the headers ! but i'm glad i could help you! this 3 commands from my answer helped you because you got your missing files from that repository

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully installed guest additions on Ubuntu 16.04 over VirtualBox 5.0.20 by simply inserting the guest additions cd from the `device` menu of Virtual machine.

Comment: I need to install guest additions on kali2 virtual machine, not ubuntu.